# Map java property file with dynamic key names to POJO

Tags: java, git, jackson, properties-file

I am trying to use the [jackson-dataformat-properties](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text) library to parse the output from [maven git commit id plugin](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin) into POJOs that I can later send as json from a Spring boot REST endpoint.

One of the complications is that the property file contains dynamic key names, like "git.remote.origin.url" where the "origin" segment can be any name.

Does anyone know a way to tell jacksons JavaPropsMapper to put any key that starts with "git.remote" into a Map? It will be impossible to maintain if I have to create a POJO named Remote with setOrigin method that takes an Origin POJO. If anyone use a different name for a remote repo the parsing will fail.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27863744/3206146) answer your question?

Comment: Try to use `@JsonAnySetter` annotation for unknown properties: [Jackson deserialization with unknown dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685508/jackson-deserialization-with-unknown-dynamic-properties/17698380#17698380)